# Some confusion with typing in a new Haskell class

Tags: class, haskell, types, graph

I'm writing a graph library to learn more about building slightly larger things in Haskell, and I'm coming across an issue.

Basically, I'm trying to define `Edge`s as a set of two points, a `from` point and a `to` point. But, I've got multiple types of edges (Weighted/not), and I do not want them to be able to mix in `graph`s.

So, the idea I had was to make a couple of new classes, `Weighted` and `Edgy`, in order to be able to achieve the amount of polymorphic behavior I'm striving towards. Both types of `Edge` will be `Edgy`, but only the Weighted `Edge` type will be `Weighted`.

The `Weighted` class is simple, because it only has to modify the entire object. This is what it looks like:

```
class Weighted a where
  modifyWeight :: (Unbounded Int -> Unbounded Int) -> a -> a
```

where `Unbounded` is a Num type I threw together to support Infinitely large and small numbers. It's simple enough, though, because I only have to return an `a`.

What I'm stuck on is getting the `Edgy` class to return something of the type of the class type (??? Not really sure how to put this, inner type, maybe?). To make this clearer, here's what I'm working with, might make more sense:

```
class Edgy a where
  to :: a -> Vertex a
  from :: a -> Vertex a
```

where `Vertex` is a wrapper class -- the `Edge` declarations that I'm trying to make here here:

```
data Edge a = Edge (Vertex a) (Vertex a) deriving (Show, Eq)

data WEdge a = WEdge (Vertex a) (Vertex a) (Unbounded Int) deriving (Show, Eq)
```

So, what I'm really trying to do is say "Okay, if you're a member of the `Edgy` class, you should be able to return a `Vertex` of the type of the `Edge`".

However, GHC doesn't like this, because the `a` type in `Edgy` ends up being `Edge a` instead of `a`, and I'm not sure how to get it to "descend" into the class to pull that type out in order to return it.

If any of this is unclear, please leave a comment.

Any help is greatly appreciated; I'm stumped!

Thanks!

Comment: It would help if you said what instances you expect `Edgy` to have, and what types you'd like `to` and `from` to have for those instances. That said, I'm not convinced that you even need type classes here--is the extra complexity really pulling its weight (ha, ha) in practice?

Comment: I would like to have `Edge a` and `WEdge a` instances of `Edgy`. 

Maybe I should dumb down the program a little bit, you're probably right about the extra complexity being unnecessary. I am trying to get a feel of what it's like to build something a little larger, though, so that was the idea behind taking this route.

Comment: If you want the functions to have types like `Edge a -> Vertex a` then the simplest thing would be what n.m.'s answer suggests. If `Edgy` really needs to care about the `a` parameter as well, things could be trickier. I'd still try to formulate it without typeclasses first and see how that looks.

Comment: By the way, you might like the built-in `Integer` type as a replacement for `Unbounded Int`.

Comment: @DanielWagner does it support Infinity? I know Integers are arbitrarily large but I want to assert that there is a number that no other number can be larger than.

Comment: @BenjaminKovach Ah! Okay. There are some libraries that provide such a type, but implementing it yourself is pretty normal, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to use type constructor classes rather than type classes

```
class Edgy e where
    to :: e a -> Vertex a
    from :: e a -> Vertex a

instance Edgy Edge where ...
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thank you! Looking at it, it seems pretty obvious, so that's something I'll definitely have to keep in mind for the future.